# gsub a text with code

Tags: lua, gsub, lua-patterns

In Lua I have the following text and want for format it:

Incoming:

```
<UNIT STYLE="BOLD">Example</UNIT>
<UNIT STYLE="HANDLE">Example 2</UNIT>
<UNIT STYLE="THR">Example 3</UNIT>
```

Expected result:

```
<BOLD>Example</BOLD>
<UNIT STYLE="HANDLE">Example 2</UNIT>
<UNIT STYLE="THR">Example 3</UNIT>
```

The values can be different (e.g. Example, This is a Text...).
How to this? Do I have to use `gsub` with a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `gsub` is the way to go:

```
s=[[
<UNIT STYLE="BOLD">Example</UNIT>
<UNIT STYLE="HANDLE">Example 2</UNIT>
<UNIT STYLE="THR">Example 3</UNIT>
]]

print(s:gsub('<UNIT STYLE="BOLD">(.-)</UNIT>','<BOLD>%1</BOLD>'))
```

Try also this:

```
print(s:gsub('<UNIT STYLE="(.-)">(.-)</UNIT>','<%1>%2<%1>'))
```

Comment: Thank you. What does the (.-) mean?

Comment: @frgtv10, `(.-)` means a captured non-greedy match. See the [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1).